# Highcharts: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, typeerror

I'm populating a highstock graph with a max of three series on. The graphs with only three series present show errors in the console:

Console Snippet:

[image]

I know that it's not a problem with the data thats being sent through; if I change the order of the series, it's always the one that renders last (the third) to error.

**Interestingly, if I resize the window or show and hide one of the other series, the series that apparently failed displays correctly!?!**

This is apparently where the error comes about:

> pointStart:b.xData[0]

xData must be undefined, but how? The data sent through is fine.

Here is how I render each of the three series:

```
    if (seriesData[0].length != 0) {
         flowDataChart.addSeries({
             name: 'Local Log Data',
             data: seriesData[0],
             zIndex: 10,
             tooltip: {
                 valueSuffix: ' Ml/day'
             }
         }, false);
     };

     if (seriesData[1].length != 0) {
         flowDataChart.addSeries({
             name: 'Ultrasonic / Probe Data',
             data: seriesData[1],
             zIndex: 20,
             tooltip: {
                 valueSuffix: ' Ml/day'
             }
         }, false);
     };

     if (seriesData[2].length != 0) {
             flowDataChart.addSeries({
                 name: $('#DownloadDataDropDown option[value="uploadFile"]').text(),
                 data: seriesData[2],
                 zIndex: 30,
                 tooltip: {
                     valueSuffix: ' Ml/day'
                 }
             }, false);
     }
```

In this example, seriesData[2] fails to load correctly.

I redraw the graph, after the series have been added.

What's going on here?

> **UPDATE:**
>
> Here is a jsfiddle I wrote that suffers the same issue -
>   http://jsfiddle.net/GMason/k61rpakx/8/

Comment: Try using; if (seriesData[2] != undefined). Instead of checking length before you check to see if seriesData[2] exist.

Comment: @DonaldPowell Thanks for your help - I've tried that and I'm still getting the same error. It's strange how it's always the third series to fail. For example if I were to change the order and place dataSeries[0] last and dataSeries[2] first, datSeries[2] would show fine and dataSeries[0] would error?!

Comment: Try to debug with console. console.log(seriesData) after each if statement

Comment: @DonaldPowell I've done that previously too - the data is exactly how you'd expect it. I know it's always the last 'addSeries' statement because I've used try catches and logged the catch statement with additional text. It's been driving me mad all day.

Comment: Could you try to recreate the problem in a working JSFiddle demo? Also, try to get rid of $('#DownloadDataDropDown option[value="uploadFile"]').text() as a name of the third series and set a normal string.

Comment: @d_paul I'll give it a go and see if I can replicate the error. I won't be able to return the exact data as it's called from a database with LINQ, but nevertheless I'll try and get the same structure set up

Comment: @d_paul Have a look at this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GMason/k61rpakx/7/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You can check series before the chart creation. Then, use all accepted series in chart's options. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xL9Lbg7s/.